# Git Clone a specific tag into a specified folder

Tags: git

I know I can clone recursively (in parallel) a specific tag of a repository with this command:

```
git clone --recursive -j8 https://github.com/repo_here/repo_name.git --tags tags/release-1.1.1
```

The contents of the repo tag will be downloaded to `tags/release-1.1.1` folder. What if I want to download the contents into `release-1.1.1` folder instead (don't want the `tags` folder)?

I read from the help page of the `git` command, it said:

```
usage: git clone [<options>] [--] <repo> [<dir>]

    -v, --verbose         be more verbose
    -q, --quiet           be more quiet
    --progress            force progress reporting
    --reject-shallow      don't clone shallow repository
    -n, --no-checkout     don't create a checkout
    --bare                create a bare repository
    --mirror              create a mirror repository (implies bare)
    -l, --local           to clone from a local repository
    --no-hardlinks        don't use local hardlinks, always copy
    -s, --shared          setup as shared repository
    --recurse-submodules[=<pathspec>]
                          initialize submodules in the clone
    --recursive ...       alias of --recurse-submodules
    -j, --jobs <n>        number of submodules cloned in parallel
    --template <template-directory>
                          directory from which templates will be used
    --reference <repo>    reference repository
    --reference-if-able <repo>
                          reference repository
    --dissociate          use --reference only while cloning
    -o, --origin <name>   use <name> instead of 'origin' to track upstream
    -b, --branch <branch>
                          checkout <branch> instead of the remote's HEAD
    -u, --upload-pack <path>
                          path to git-upload-pack on the remote
    --depth <depth>       create a shallow clone of that depth
    --shallow-since <time>
                          create a shallow clone since a specific time
    --shallow-exclude <revision>
                          deepen history of shallow clone, excluding rev
    --single-branch       clone only one branch, HEAD or --branch
    --no-tags             don't clone any tags, and make later fetches not to follow them
    --shallow-submodules  any cloned submodules will be shallow
    --separate-git-dir <gitdir>
                          separate git dir from working tree
    -c, --config <key=value>
                          set config inside the new repository
    --server-option <server-specific>
                          option to transmit
    -4, --ipv4            use IPv4 addresses only
    -6, --ipv6            use IPv6 addresses only
    --filter <args>       object filtering
    --also-filter-submodules
                          apply partial clone filters to submodules
    --remote-submodules   any cloned submodules will use their remote-tracking branch
    --sparse              initialize sparse-checkout file to include only files at root
    --bundle-uri <uri>    a URI for downloading bundles before fetching from origin remote
```

The last argument should be a local path, isn't it?

But when I add a path at the end of the above command, this error occurs:

> fatal: Too many arguments.

Of course, I know I can chain the command with `&& mv tags/release-1.1.1 . && rm -rf tags/`, but can I achieve my goal with only `git clone` command?

Thanks.

Git version 2.41.0 (macOS Ventura 13.4.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--tags` is not a valid option, at least since v2.27.0.

`tags/release-1.1.1` is the `[<dir>]` in `git clone [<options>] [--] <repo> [<dir>]` that represents the local path. It is not the value of the option `--tags` even if `--tags` is valid.

To clone the repository into `release-1.1.1` and check out the specific tag `release-1.1.1`,

```
git clone --recursive -j8 https://github.com/repo_here/repo_name.git -b release-1.1.1 -- release-1.1.1
```

The last `--` is optional. It has spaces at both sides. It's used to disambiguate a revision and a path, though in this case there is no ambiguity. I personally tend to always add it.

Reference:

[-b <name>, --branch <name>](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-clone/2.27.0#Documentation/git-clone.txt--bltnamegt).

The optional " -- " in [gitcli](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitcli).

Comment: Omg. I used this `--tags` flag a few years ago, and it reports no error. I never thought it was invalid. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Raptor Maybe it's been deprecated or a no-op. It cannot be found in the manual.